# ObjectId do MongoDB retornando [object Object] no Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mongodb

Em uma consulta que faço no MongoDB utilizando Ajax e PHP, quando vou manipular o ObjectId já no javascript, este me retorna como [object Object].
Como faço para utilizá-lo como string?

Segue código $.ajax()

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'funcoes/registroeventos.php',
    data: {
        "ref": ref
    },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    success: function (dados) {
        $.each(dados, function () {
            $.each(this, function (index, value) {
                alert(value);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Segue o código PHP:

```
$ref = $_POST['ref'];
    try {
        $consulta = ['ref' => $ref, 'excluido' => 'n'];
        $opcoes = [];
        $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($consulta, $opcoes);
        $linhas = $conexao->executeQuery($bd . "maquinas", $query);

        echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($linhas));
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
```

Exemplo do `Json`:

```
[
     {"_id":{"$oid":"5aafac02dc32b7f93a3fda00"}, "ref":"DIP001", 
      "nome":"Dip Tork", "status":"setup", "excluido":"n",
       "idsetor":"5aafaba2dc32b7f93a3fd9ff"} 
]
```

Comment: Tem o exemplo do Javascript

Comment: Você diz o json?
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5aafac02dc32b7f93a3fda00"}, "ref":"DIP001", "nome":"Dip Tork", "status":"setup", "excluido":"n", "idsetor":"5aafaba2dc32b7f93a3fd9ff"} ]

Comment: Isso aí vc não consegue pegar o valor?

Comment: Tentei acessar de várias formas. Mas sempre me retorna como [object Object]. Todos os outros valores ele retornar normal. Mas o ObjectId sempre como object.

Comment: eu fiz um exemplo naquele `json` do comentário !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo seu comentário, percebe que teve dificuldades em entender, esse `JSON` na verdade é um `array` de informações, ou seja, tem posições para cada item, exemplo:

```js
let item = [{"_id":{"$oid":"5aafac02dc32b7f93a3fda00"}, 
             "ref":"DIP001", "nome":"Dip Tork", 
              "status":"setup", "excluido":"n",
               "idsetor":"5aafaba2dc32b7f93a3fd9ff"} ] ;

console.log(item[0]['_id']['$oid']);
console.log(item[0]['ref']);
console.log(item[0]['nome']);
console.log(item[0]['status']);
console.log(item[0]['excluido']);
console.log(item[0]['idsetor']);
```

nesse caso exemplo, só tem um item no `array` que é o `0`, mas, se contiver mais tem que verificar a quantidade de items no `array` para buscar seus itens, exemplo:

```js
let item = [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5aafac02dc32b7f93a3fda00"
  },
  "ref": "DIP001",
  "nome": "Dip Tork",
  "status": "setup",
  "excluido": "n",
  "idsetor": "5aafaba2dc32b7f93a3fd9ff"
}, {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5aafac02dc32b7f93a3fdaaa"
  },
  "ref": "DIP001",
  "nome": "Dip Tork",
  "status": "setup",
  "excluido": "n",
  "idsetor": "5aafaba2dc32b7f93a3fd9ff"
}];
console.log('Quantidade de itens:' + item.length);
for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  console.log('-----------------------------');
  console.log(item[i]['_id']['$oid']);
  console.log(item[i]['ref']);
  console.log(item[i]['nome']);
  console.log(item[i]['status']);
  console.log(item[i]['excluido']);
  console.log(item[i]['idsetor']);  
}
```

Comment: Realmente estava faltando eu fazer a referência certa. Estava tentado alert(dados._id); ao invés de alert(dados._id.$oid);